# Playing sounds sequentially HTML5

Tags: html, audio

In HTML5, is there an easy way to group audio clips together? I'm hoping to play 3 extremely short mp3s sequentially, but unfortunately it's key that there is no lag between them. I also need to have one play button for all of them. Thanks to anyone who knows,

N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant do this entirely with HTML5, you will need to add jQuery or some other javascript library to help you accomplish this. I recently created a mobile web app that used [this](http://blog.lastrose.com/html5-audio-video-playlist/) tutorial as a starting point. You can check out an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lastrose/vkMqR/). Essentially all you need to do is modify the default functionality of the HTML5 audio player, and then make it do what you want.

HTML:

```
<audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" >
    <source src="http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3">
    Your Fallback goes here
</audio>

<ul id="playlist">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="http://www.archive.org/download/bolero_69/Bolero.mp3">
                Ravel Bolero
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.archive.org/download/MoonlightSonata_755/Beethoven-MoonlightSonata.mp3">
                Moonlight Sonata - Beethoven
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.archive.org/download/CanonInD_261/CanoninD.mp3">
                Canon in D Pachabel
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.archive.org/download/PatrikbkarlChamberSymph/PatrikbkarlChamberSymph_vbr_mp3.zip">
                patrikbkarl chamber symph
            </a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
var audio;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;

init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('audio');
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length - 1;
    audio[0].volume = .10;
    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        run(link, audio[0]);
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
            link = playlist.find('a')[0];
        }else{
            link = playlist.find('a')[current];    
        }
        run($(link),audio[0]);
    });
}
function run(link, player){
        player.src = link.attr('href');
        par = link.parent();
        par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();
}
```

Source: http://blog.lastrose.com/html5-audio-video-playlist/

Comment: Right, I'm using the play framework: would you suggest going down this route or combining the files with Scala and then serving them?

Comment: I honestly dont have much experience with Scala, so I dont think I could give you answer. With other programming languages I usually go the jQuery route just because its easily implemented and doesnt add much overhead to your application.